# How would you do a "not in" query with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two collections which have property `Email` in both collections. I need to get a list of the items in the first list where `Email` does not exist in the second list. With SQL I would just use "not in", but I do not know the equivalent in LINQ. How is that done?

So far I have a join, like...

```
var matches = from item1 in list1
join item2 in list2 on item1.Email equals item2.Email
select new { Email = list1.Email };
```

But I cannot join since I need the difference and the join would fail. I need some way of using Contains or Exists I believe. I just have not found an example to do that yet.

Comment: Please note that Echostorm's answer produces code that is much clearer to read than Robert's

Answer (score 337, accepted):

I don't know if this will help you but..

```
NorthwindDataContext dc = new NorthwindDataContext();    
dc.Log = Console.Out;

var query =    
    from c in dc.Customers    
    where !(from o in dc.Orders    
            select o.CustomerID)    
           .Contains(c.CustomerID)    
    select c;

foreach (var c in query) Console.WriteLine( c );
```

from [The NOT IN clause in LINQ to SQL](https://web.archive.org/web/20120321161927/https://www.programminglinq.com/blogs/marcorusso/archive/2008/01/14/the-not-in-clause-in-linq-to-sql.aspx) by [Marco Russo](https://web.archive.org/web/20110805143247/http://introducinglinq.com/blogs/marcorusso/default.aspx)

Comment: But i use linq to entities , so i get "only primitive types can be used error". Is there any work around...? apart from manually iterating and finding the list.

Comment: This works fine for me with LINQ to Entities. The SQL becomes a WHERE NOT EXISTS(subquery) query. Maybe there was an update that addressed this?

Comment: I think newer versions of EF do support .Contains, plus this question doesn't tag EF (version) or LinqToSQL.. so there may be a need to scope the question and answer here..

Comment: @Robert Rouse - The link to The Not in cluse in linq to sql no longer works.  Just an fyi.

Comment: The link provided leads to a site flagged as containing malware.

Answer (score 361):

You want the Except operator.

```
var answer = list1.Except(list2);
```

Better explanation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/charlie/linq-farm-more-on-set-operators

**NOTE:** This technique works best for primitive types only, since you have to implement an [IEqualityComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1) to use the `Except` method with complex types.

Comment: Using Except: If you work with complex types lists, then you have to implement an IEqualityComparer<MyComlplexType>, which it makes it not that nice

Comment: You don't **have** to implement IEqualityComparer<T> if you just want to compare reference equality or if you've overridden T.Equals() and T.GetHashCode().  If you don't implement IEqualityComparer<T>, [EqualityComparer<T>.Default](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17225006/1925996) will be used.

Comment: @Echostorm (and others reading), if you do a Select to Anonymous object, the HashCode will be determined by the property values; `list1.Select(item => new { Property1 = item.Property1, Property2 = item.Property2 }).Except(list2.Select( item => new { Property1 = item.Property1, Property2 = item.Property2 }));` this is particular useful when you're determining equality by evaluating only a set of values of the complex type.

Comment: Actually, someone pointed out below, and I think correctly, that there wouldn't be a need to implement `IEquatityComparor<T,T>` or override object comparison methods in a `LinqToSql` scenario; for, the query will be represented as/compiled to/expressed as SQL; thus the values will be checked, not the object reference.

Comment: Using the `except` I was able to speed up a LINQ query from 8-10 seconds to a half a second

Comment: Was pleasantly surprised when this generated a SQL Server EXCEPT statement for me. Beautiful

Comment: Combining the new [`ExceptBy()` starts from .NET 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70135623/net-6-intersectby-and-exceptby-examples) and [`ValueTuple<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple), we can do `list1.ExceptBy(list2.Select(i => (i.Prop1, i.Prop2)), i => (i.Prop1, i.Prop2))`;

Answer (score 76):

For people who start with a group of in-memory objects and are querying against a database, I've found this to be the best way to go:

```
var itemIds = inMemoryList.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();
var otherObjects = context.ItemList.Where(x => !itemIds.Contains(x.Id));
```

This produces a nice `WHERE ... IN (...)` clause in SQL.

Comment: actually, you can do that in 3.5

Answer (score 62):

> items in the first list where the Email does not exist in the second list.

```
from item1 in List1
where !(list2.Any(item2 => item2.Email == item1.Email))
select item1;
```

Answer (score 21):

You can use a combination of Where and Any for finding not in:

```
var NotInRecord =list1.Where(p => !list2.Any(p2 => p2.Email  == p.Email));
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Whenever I start looking at `.Any()`, especially when it's "NOT ANY" I get confused!

Answer (score 8):

One could also use `All()`

```
var notInList = list1.Where(p => list2.All(p2 => p2.Email != p.Email));
```

Answer (score 7):

In the case where one is using the [ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework), EchoStorm's solution also works perfectly. But it took me a few minutes to wrap my head around it. Assuming you have a database context, dc, and want to find rows in table x not linked in table y, the complete answer answer looks like:

```
var linked =
  from x in dc.X
  from y in dc.Y
  where x.MyProperty == y.MyProperty
  select x;
var notLinked =
  dc.X.Except(linked);
```

In response to Andy's comment, yes, one can have two from's in a LINQ query. Here's a complete working example, using lists. Each class, Foo and Bar, has an Id. Foo has a "foreign key" reference to Bar via Foo.BarId. The program selects all Foo's not linked to a corresponding Bar.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Creates some foos
        List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>();
        fooList.Add(new Foo { Id = 1, BarId = 11 });
        fooList.Add(new Foo { Id = 2, BarId = 12 });
        fooList.Add(new Foo { Id = 3, BarId = 13 });
        fooList.Add(new Foo { Id = 4, BarId = 14 });
        fooList.Add(new Foo { Id = 5, BarId = -1 });
        fooList.Add(new Foo { Id = 6, BarId = -1 });
        fooList.Add(new Foo { Id = 7, BarId = -1 });

        // Create some bars
        List<Bar> barList = new List<Bar>();
        barList.Add(new Bar { Id = 11 });
        barList.Add(new Bar { Id = 12 });
        barList.Add(new Bar { Id = 13 });
        barList.Add(new Bar { Id = 14 });
        barList.Add(new Bar { Id = 15 });
        barList.Add(new Bar { Id = 16 });
        barList.Add(new Bar { Id = 17 });

        var linked = from foo in fooList
                     from bar in barList
                     where foo.BarId == bar.Id
                     select foo;
        var notLinked = fooList.Except(linked);
        foreach (Foo item in notLinked)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                String.Format(
                "Foo.Id: {0} | Bar.Id: {1}",
                item.Id, item.BarId));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BarId { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: do two froms wor in LINQ? that would be helpfull.

Comment: Andy: Yes, see revised answer above.

Answer (score 5):

You can take both the collections in two different lists, say list1 and list2.

Then just write

```
list1.RemoveAll(Item => list2.Contains(Item));
```

This will work.

Comment: Nice but has the side effect of removing elements from the list.

Comment: That's not a query, that's a manipulation of the data to get the result. I would NOT recommend using this approach.

Answer (score 4):

```
var secondEmails = (from item in list2
                    select new { Email = item.Email }
                   ).ToList();

var matches = from item in list1
              where !secondEmails.Contains(item.Email)
              select new {Email = item.Email};
```

Answer (score 3):

While `Except` is part of the answer, it's not the whole answer.  By default, `Except` (like several of the LINQ operators) does a reference comparison on reference types.  To compare by values in the objects, you'll have to

- implement `IEquatable<T>` in your type, or
- override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in your type, or
- pass in an instance of a type implementing `IEqualityComparer<T>` for your type

Comment: ... if we are talking about LINQ to Objects. If it was LINQ to SQL, the query is translated into SQL statements that run on the database, so this doesn't apply.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can do like this:

```
var result = list1.Where(p => list2.All(x => x.Id != p.Id));
```

Answer (score 1):

Example using List of int for simplicity.

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
// fill data
List<int> list2 = new List<int>();
// fill data

var results = from i in list1
              where !list2.Contains(i)
              select i;

foreach (var result in results)
    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who also wants to use a SQL-alike `IN` operator in C#, download this package :

> Mshwf.NiceLinq

It has `In` and `NotIn` methods:

```
var result = list1.In(x => x.Email, list2.Select(z => z.Email));
```

Even you can use it this way

```
var result = list1.In(x => x.Email, "a@b.com", "b@c.com", "c@d.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not test this with [LINQ to Entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework#LINQ_to_Entities):

```
NorthwindDataContext dc = new NorthwindDataContext();    
dc.Log = Console.Out;

var query =    
    from c in dc.Customers 
    where !dc.Orders.Any(o => o.CustomerID == c.CustomerID)   
    select c;
```

Alternatively:

```
NorthwindDataContext dc = new NorthwindDataContext();    
dc.Log = Console.Out;

var query =    
    from c in dc.Customers 
    where dc.Orders.All(o => o.CustomerID != c.CustomerID)   
    select c;

foreach (var c in query) 
    Console.WriteLine( c );
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do an outer join, only selecting the items from the first list if the group is empty? Something like:

```
Dim result = (From a In list1
              Group Join b In list2 
                  On a.Value Equals b.Value 
                  Into grp = Group
              Where Not grp.Any
              Select a)
```

I'm unsure whether this would work in any sort of efficient way with the Entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

```
 DynamicWebsiteEntities db = new DynamicWebsiteEntities();
    var data = (from dt_sub in db.Subjects_Details
                                //Sub Query - 1
                            let sub_s_g = (from sg in db.Subjects_In_Group
                                           where sg.GroupId == groupId
                                           select sg.SubjectId)
                            //Where Cause
                            where !sub_s_g.Contains(dt_sub.Id) && dt_sub.IsLanguage == false
                            //Order By Cause
                            orderby dt_sub.Subject_Name

                            select dt_sub)
                           .AsEnumerable();
                  
                                SelectList multiSelect = new SelectList(data, "Id", "Subject_Name", selectedValue);

    //======================================OR===========================================

    var data = (from dt_sub in db.Subjects_Details

                               
                            //Where Cause
                            where !(from sg in db.Subjects_In_Group
                                           where sg.GroupId == groupId
                                           select sg.SubjectId).Contains(dt_sub.Id) && dt_sub.IsLanguage == false

                            //Order By Cause
                            orderby dt_sub.Subject_Name

                            select dt_sub)

                           .AsEnumerable();
```