# Exclude rows in Lambda Expression

Tags: lambda, linq-to-entities

I have this Linq-to-Entities expression

```
return
                (from aa in DataContext.AccommodationAmenities
                 join a in DataContext.Amenities
                     on aa.AmenityId equals a.Id
                 where a.LowerCaseAmenity.Contains(lowerCaseSearchTerm)
                 select new AmenitySummary
                            {
                                AmenityId = a.Id,
                                Amenity = a.Amenity1,
                                LowerCaseAmenity = selected//a.LowerCaseAmenity
                            }).Distinct();
```

And I also have a string array which contains amenities that I want to exclude from this list.  Is there some way of doing something like this at the end

```
.Exclude(a => a.Amentiy == stringArray)
```

So basically, stringArray contains amenities some of which will equal Amenity in AmenitySummary.  If they equal I don't want to add that to the result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183791/how-would-you-do-a-not-in-query-with-linq may be related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
return
                (from aa in DataContext.AccommodationAmenities
                 join a in DataContext.Amenities
                     on aa.AmenityId equals a.Id
                 where a.LowerCaseAmenity.Contains(lowerCaseSearchTerm)
                       && !stringArray.Contains(a.Amenity1)
                 select new AmenitySummary
                            {
                                AmenityId = a.Id,
                                Amenity = a.Amenity1,
                                LowerCaseAmenity = selected//a.LowerCaseAmenity
                            }).Distinct();
```