# Can I accomplish this SQL query in Linq?

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a list, and I want to grab two sets of rows from that list based on myID value.  However, I don't want to grab 2 items with the same value in "myOtherField".  This is easy enough in SQL.  Can I accomplish this in Linq?

```
select * from myTable where myID = 25

union

select * from myTable where myID = 35
and myOtherField not in (select myOtherField from myTable where myID = 25)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386993.aspx

[How would you do a "not in" query with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183791/how-would-you-do-a-not-in-query-with-linq)

```
var query =
(from obj in MyTable
select obj)
.Union
    (from obj in Mytable
where obj.myid = 35 && !(from obj.myotherfield in mytable   
        select obj)    
       .Contains(obj => obj.myid=25)    
    select obj)
```

;