# how to write a linq query which make s.th. like where id != List<id>

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would you do a “not in” query with Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183791/how-would-you-do-a-not-in-query-with-linq)

I have a question about a LINQ query, I have a `List<int> foo;` and now I need to check something like:

```
var output = select a from db.User where a.id not in foo select a;
```

how can i realize this: **a.id not in foo** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `foo` is a list then `where !foo.Contains(a.id)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the contains method on the list

```
var output = from a in db.User where !foo.Contains(a.id) select a;
```

Comment: i think that will lead to syntax error...

Comment: @PranayRana I didn't fully read the entire LINQ statement, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

My Blog about this : [SQL to LINQ ( Case 7 - Filter data by using IN and NOT IN clause)](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2010/12/sql-to-linq-case-7-filter-data-by-using_15.html)

You use, `where <list>.Contains( <item> )`

```
var foo = {1, 2, 3};
var users = from p in db.users
                 where !foo.Contains(p.id)
                 select p;
```

Image Representation of this

[image]