# Get All Except from SQL database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a list of Products like this

```
var r = db.Products.Where(x => x.Sites
                                .Where(z => z.Key == associatedProducts.Key)
                                .Any()
                  ).ToList()
```

There is an entity called Products, I want to get all elements from products except those exist in associatedProducts.Products

How can i do that ?

Comment: can you show the code related to creating associatedProducts?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following query works if associatedProducts list is fetched using EF in a previos query.

```
var temp = db.Products.ToList().Except(associatedProducts).ToList();
```

otherwise, if `associatedProducts` is a list which has not been fetched using EF (assuming `Key` is an integer);

```
List<int> tempIdList = associatedProducts.Select(q => q.Key ).ToList();
var temp = db.Products.Where(q => !tempIdList.Contains(q.Key));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            var query = from p in db.Products
                        where !(from a in associatedProducts.Products
                                select a.Products)
                                .Contains(p.Key)
                        select p;
```

I didn't test the query, but it should look like this.

You should have a look at how you can use "not in" in linq:
[How would you do a "not in" query with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183791/how-would-you-do-a-not-in-query-with-linq)

Answer (score 0):

In the Context of EF6 . I assume that there is one to many relation with Product and
AssociatedProduct entities. So you can use navigation properties to find the specified result.

```
public class AssociatedProduct
{
    [Key]
    public int kye { get; set; }
    ......
    ......
    public List<Products> Products { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int key { get; set; }
    .........
    .........
    public AssociatedProduct  AssociatedProduct { get; set; }

}
```

If entity classes are defined as shown above below query will generate all Products that are not Associated.

```
 var productsNotAssociated = _dbctx.Product
                             .Where(p=> p.AssociatedProduct == null)
                             .ToList();
```

Answer (score -4):

You can load the list of products that you want to exclude, and then `.Exclude()` it from the list of all products.