# What is the default equality comparer for a set type?

Tags: c#

In the MSDN API for the [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) constructor with no arguments it states

> Initializes a new instance of the HashSet class that is empty and
>   uses the default equality comparer for the set type.

What is the default equality comparer for the set type, e.g. for a custom class?

BTW: Is it just me or is the MSDN API documentation really a bit thin on explanations? I stumble about such questions more than once when reading it.

Comment: it is not just you, the docs are poor

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It means it will use the comparer returned by [`EqualityComparer<T>.Default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1.default) for the element type `T` of the set.

As the documentation states:

> The Default property checks whether type `T` implements the
> System.IEquatable interface and, if so, returns an
> EqualityComparer that uses that implementation. Otherwise, it
> returns an EqualityComparer that uses the overrides of
> Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode provided by `T`.

So for your custom type, it will use the `GetHashCode` method you have defined to locate items in the set. If you have implemented `IEquatable<T>` it will use `IEquatable<T>.Equals(T)` for equality, otherwise it will use your `Equals(object)` method. This method defaults to reference equality as defined in the `object` class. Therefore if you are defining equality using either method, you should ensure you also override `GetHashCode` as well.

Comment: Just a comment. The `EqualityComparer<CustomClass>.Default` will malfunction (and so `HashSet<CustomClass>` will malfunction) if `CustomClass` implements `IEquatable<CustomClass>` ***without*** overriding `GetHashCode()`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen This is a good point I just stumbled over in a little example I wrote. Why is implementing `IEquatable<CustomClass>` not sufficient? The statement in Lee's answer says that at first it will look up if `IEquatable` is implemented, and if not, `Object.Equals` and `Object.GetHashCode` will be used.

Comment: @JohnThreepwood - `GetHashCode` is always used, the version of `Equals` that is used depends on whether the class implements `IEquatable<T>` or not.

Comment: @JohnThreepwood Well, it needs a hash code for each item, and it's not going to examine the body of your `IEquatable<>` `Equals` method to see if it can come up with a hash code algorithm from that!! So how ***could*** it work? It's a pity you don't get a compiler warning in this situation, like the one you get when you override `Equals(object)` without overriding `GetHashCode()`.

Answer (score 11):

By default, it will delegate to `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`. This returns a comparer that can compare two objects of type `T`.

For a custom class, this does a few things in this order:

- if the class implements `IEquatable<T>`, it will delegate to the class's implementation of this interface
- if the class has an `Equals` method defined, it will use that
- as a last resort, it will use reference equality