# Why does SequenceEqual take an IEqualityComparer rather than a predicate?

Tags: .net, linq-to-objects

Why does [Enumerable.SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342073.aspx) take its comparer as an [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms132151.aspx)? The algorithm seems to make no use of [GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms132155.aspx). Why does it not instead take a `Func<TSource, TSource, bool>` predicate, similar to how [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535050.aspx) takes a `Func<TSource, bool>`?

Comment: Off-topic IMO, see my comments below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that .NET Core is open source, I posted this question as an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2114) on GitHub. Hopefully, that will translate into an answer or an improvement.

---

Update - details on the possible rationale for the existing design and its issues, taken from the GitHub issue:

> `IEqualityComparer`, despite its name, really does two things: hashes
>   and checks for equality. The only behavioral difference between a
>   `Func<TSource, TSource, bool>` and `IEqualityComparer` is that
>   `IEqualityComparer` has a `GetHashCode` method. If all you want to do
>   is check for sequence equality, with `IEqualityComparer` you have to
>   write the hashing code (which can be tricky to do well), even though
>   it will likely never be used (but you can't count on it never being
>   used because `SequenceEqual` doesn't document that it won't use it).
>
> Often, types that you compare with `SequenceEqual` will happen to have
>   one or more`IEqualityComparer` companion types so that they can be
>   stored in hashed containers. Probably, that is why `IEqualityComparer`
>   was chosen as the parameter. However, there are also plenty of times
>   when there isn't an `IEqualityComparer` and there is no hashing
>   requirement. In those cases, having to create a class and implement
>   `GetHashCode` is wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

I am tempted to say "because".

If you look around at other similar methods (like [Enumerable.Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx)) they also take an `IEqualityComparer` in the overload.

Also, an `IEqualityComparer` is the "correct" way to check if objects are equal. A `Func<TSource, TSource, bool>` would not neccessarily check for equality, it would check if the objects are similar enough for your specific usage at this moment in time.

Luckily it is easy enough to make your own extension method. For instance does [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) have a implementation of `DistinctBy` that you can look at.

Comment: `Distinct` needs `GetHashCode` so that it can build a hash table to do the many-to-many comparison. Other methods that take `IEqualityComparer` are similar. `SequenceEqual` is "distinct" :-) in that it is a simple linear operation that doesn't need a hash table.

Comment: I don't think there is any real difference between equal and equal enough at the moment.

Comment: I respectfully disagree :) SequenceEqual both that both enumerables are of the same length, that the objects in the enumerables are in the same order, and that they are equal. The "proper" way to check for equality is an equalitycomparer.

If you do not care about "proper equality" you could envision a Enumerable.SequenceEqualEnough<T, S> passing in two Func's (one for T and one for S) that would select "something" to compare the two enumerables by. Now you can even check if enumerables of different types are "equal enough".

Comment: Could you clarify what you disagree with? I'm not suggesting that an `IEqualityComparer` won't work or shouldn't be supported if you happen to have one laying around. But if you want to compare sequences without one (e.g. because their objects are never stored in a hashing container), having to create a class just to do a comparison is a lot heavier than a simple lambda method.

Comment: I do not directly see what the hashing has to do with anything. The equalitycomparer is used for the Equals method. If you are referring to EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default; which is used for comparer if you do not specify one, that is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224940/what-is-the-default-equality-comparer-for-a-set-type

And as for the hashing container, well, sometimes they are?

Comment: Ah, I got your reference to the hashing container now, I think, so ignore the last bit. I would like to append "... then it is consistent" to my previous "because" statement :)

Comment: The only behavioral difference between a `Func<TSource, TSource, bool>` and `IEqualityComparer` is that `IEqualityComparer` has a `GetHashCode` method. If all you want to do is check for sequence equality, with `IEqualityComparer` you have to write the hashing code (which can be tricky to do well), even though it will likely never be used (but you can't count on it never being used because `SequenceEqual` doesn't document that it won't use it).

Comment: @EdwardBrey You should add this last comment to your question. I think you've got a point here, although I still don't think it's on-topic here, because it's about an implementation detail that we can't do anything about, and the reasons of which we can only guess. So basically I agree, the answer is "because".

Comment: I expanded on the comment and added it to my answer. Now that .NET Core is open source, we can do something about the implementation detail - if there's a problem, we can submit a pull request. However, I doubt there's any problem with the implementation. It's the interface (i.e. the method signature) that seems to need enhancing. An overload for each form of comparison seems like the best choice. IMHO, the question about whether this is true and the underlying design decision is on topic. I can only guess, but perhaps an authoritative answer exists. You only find out if you ask.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really answering your question, but here are the overloads:

```
    public static bool SequenceEqual<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second,
        Func<TSource, TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        return first.SequenceEqual(second, new PredicateEqualityComparer<TSource>(predicate));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Join<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TOuter> outer, IEnumerable<TInner> inner, Func<TOuter, TKey> outerKeySelector, Func<TInner, TKey> innerKeySelector, Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult> resultSelector, Func<TKey, TKey, bool> predicate)
    {
        return outer.Join(inner, outerKeySelector, innerKeySelector, resultSelector, new PredicateEqualityComparer<TKey>(predicate));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> GroupJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TOuter> outer,
        IEnumerable<TInner> inner, Func<TOuter, TKey> outerKeySelector, Func<TInner, TKey> innerKeySelector,
        Func<TOuter, IEnumerable<TInner>, TResult> resultSelector, Func<TKey, TKey, bool> predicate)
    {
        return outer.GroupJoin(inner, outerKeySelector, innerKeySelector, resultSelector,
            new PredicateEqualityComparer<TKey>(predicate));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> GroupBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TKey, TKey, bool> predicate)
    {
        return source.GroupBy(keySelector, new PredicateEqualityComparer<TKey>(predicate));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TElement>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector, Func<TKey, TKey, bool> predicate)
    {
        return source.GroupBy(keySelector, elementSelector, new PredicateEqualityComparer<TKey>(predicate));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TSource>, TResult> resultSelector,
        Func<TKey, TKey, bool> predicate)
    {
        return source.GroupBy(keySelector, resultSelector, new PredicateEqualityComparer<TKey>(predicate));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TElement, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector,
        Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TElement>, TResult> resultSelector, Func<TKey, TKey, bool> predicate)
    {
        return source.GroupBy(keySelector, elementSelector, resultSelector, new PredicateEqualityComparer<TKey>(predicate));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Distinct<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        return source.Distinct(new PredicateEqualityComparer<TSource>(predicate));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Union<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, Func<TSource, TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        return first.Union(second, new PredicateEqualityComparer<TSource>(predicate));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Intersect<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
        IEnumerable<TSource> second, Func<TSource, TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        return first.Intersect(second, new PredicateEqualityComparer<TSource>(predicate));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Except<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second,
        Func<TSource, TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        return first.Except(second, new PredicateEqualityComparer<TSource>(predicate));
    }

    public static Dictionary<TKey, TSource> ToDictionary<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TKey, TKey, bool> predicate)
    {
        return source.ToDictionary(keySelector, new PredicateEqualityComparer<TKey>(predicate));
    }

    public static Dictionary<TKey, TElement> ToDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector, Func<TKey, TKey, bool> predicate)
    {
        return source.ToDictionary(keySelector, elementSelector, new PredicateEqualityComparer<TKey>(predicate));
    }

    public static ILookup<TKey, TSource> ToLookup<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TKey, TKey, bool> predicate)
    {
        return source.ToLookup(keySelector, new PredicateEqualityComparer<TKey>(predicate));
    }

    public static bool Contains<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource value,
        Func<TSource, TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        return source.Contains(value, new PredicateEqualityComparer<TSource>(predicate));
    }
```

Achieved with this:

```
public class PredicateEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private Func<T, T, bool> _predicate;

    public PredicateEqualityComparer(Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
    {
        _predicate = predicate;
    }

    public bool Equals(T a, T b)
    {
        return _predicate(a, b);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T a)
    {
        return a.GetHashCode();
    }

}
```

I only tested SequenceEqual. Maybe some of those overloads don't work as expected because of the hashing. Its up to you, to think this through.