# C# - how to get distinct items from a Collection View

Tags: c#, distinct, collectionview

```
CollectionView view = CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyData);
View.Filter = i => ((MyClass)i).MyProperty;
```

I have a collection view like in the above. The problem is that the collection MyData which has already been bound to a listview contains duplicate items. How do I get unique items as the result of my filtering?

Comment: What is the type of `MyData`?

Comment: I have created a class called Test. MyData is collection of objects created from that class

Comment: I get that from the beginning. My question was for the **type**  of `MyData`, i.e. `List<MyObect>`, `MyObject[]` etc. So?

Comment: It is an observable collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method works:

```
CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(c.Items);
view.Filter = i =>
{
    var index1 = c.MyData.FindIndex(delegate (MyClass s)
    {
        return Object.ReferenceEquals(s, i);
    });
    var index2 = c.MyData.FindLastIndex(delegate (MyClass s)
    {
        return ((MyClass)i).MyProperty == s.MyProperty as string; //value comparison
    });
    return index1 == index2;
};
```

`index1` is the index of the object in the collection. You need to compare the `references` to get that.

`index2` is the last index of the `value`. There you need to compare the `value`.

So you basically compare if the `index` of the current `element` is the last one where it occurs.

**Note**:

this does not work naturally with simple types. I had to initialize my test collection like this:

`new List<string>() { new string("I1".ToCharArray()), new string("I1".ToCharArray()), "I2" };`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
var g = collection.Select(i => i.Property1).Distinct();
```

And please give a feedback, if it work.

Comment: var myData= (from d in YourList select d).Distinct();

Comment: If your using is a User-defined class, you need to implement IEquatable Interface for Distinct to use the default Comparer.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I'm late while figuring out the best solution that fits your need. Anyway I'm providing it because it's cleaner and faster than the accepted.

First as usual let define a function that encapsulates the logic

```
static bool IsDuplicate(IEnumerable<MyObject> collection, MyObject target)
{
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        // NOTE: Check only the items BEFORE the one in question
        if (ReferenceEquals(item, target)) break;
        // Your criteria goes here
        if (item.MyProperty == target.MyProperty) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and then use it

```
var view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyData);
view.Filter = item => !IsDuplicate((IEnumerable<MyClass>)view.SourceCollection, (MyClass)item);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer from @Sebastian Tam

```
var g = collection.Select(i => i.Property1).Distinct();
```

If collection is a sequence from a User-defined class of your own, you need to implement IEquatable Interface for Distinct to use the default Comparer.

Have a look at this post

[What is the default equality comparer for a set type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224940/what-is-the-default-equality-comparer-for-a-set-type)