# IEnumerable<T>.Contains is not using my own IEqualityComparer by default

Tags: c#, .net, iequalitycomparer

I implemented `IEqualityComparer` and I was getting incorrect comparisons, not even watching the debugger passing through my `Equals` method when being used by `IEnumerable.Contains` method.

```
public struct CustomMailAddress : IEqualityComparer<CustomMailAddress>
{
    public string Address { get; private set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; private set; }

    public bool IsFullAddress { get; private set; }

    public CustomMailAddress(string address)
    {
        this.Address = address;
        this.DisplayName = String.Empty;
        this.IsFullAddress = address.IndexOf('@') >= 0;
    }

    public CustomMailAddress(MailAddress address)
    {
        this.Address = address.Address;
        this.DisplayName = address.DisplayName;
        this.IsFullAddress = true;
    }

    public bool Equals(CustomMailAddress x, CustomMailAddress y)
    {
        return x.IsFullAddress ? x.Address.EndsWith(y.Address) : y.Address.EndsWith(x.Address);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(CustomMailAddress obj)
    {
        return obj.Address.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Based on the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Contains__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____0_) :

> Elements are compared to the specified value by using the default equality comparer, [Default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1.default?view=netframework-4.8).

Which leads to:

> The default instance of the EqualityComparer class for type T.

From my understanding, they say my own  comparer will be used. But this returns `false`:

```
bool isMatch = source.CollectedAddresses.Any(x => _validAddreses.Contains(x));
```

So, since it should return `true` and the debugger wasn't stopping at my `Equals` method I used the `Contains` [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Contains__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____0_System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__), getting my desired `true`.

```
bool isMatch = source.CollectedAddresses.Any(x => _validAddreses.Contains(x, new CustomMailAddress()));
```

What am I missing? Wasn't it supposed to use the `EqualityComparer` my `CustomMailAddress` has "by default"?

Comment: `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`  it using `IEquatable<T>` not `IEqualityComparer<T>`

Comment: Your class [should have implemented `IEquatable<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17224974/11683).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From my understanding, they say my own comparer will be used.

They never said that. You have misunderstood. If your understanding were correct, they would have said something like, "if `T` implements `IEqualityComparer<T>`, an instance of `T` is returned".

But think about it, how can `IEqualityComparer<T>.Default` know how to return an instance of `T`? You haven't guaranteed it any parameterless constructors or anything like that!

The "default equality comparer" actually calls the `Equals` method of `IEquatable<T>`, so I think you probably have mixed up the two interfaces. Your struct should implement `IEquatable<T>`, not `IEqualityComparer`.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that implementing `IEqualityComparer` means that the class `CustomMailAddress` can compare objects of type `CustomMailAddress`, e.g. `public struct AppleComparer: IEqualityComparer<Apple>` means that `AppleComparer` can compare Apples.

What you actually want is to override Equals and GetHashCode

```
public struct CustomMailAddress
{
    public string Address { get; private set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; private set; }

    public bool IsFullAddress { get; private set; }

    public CustomMailAddress(string address)
    {
        this.Address = address;
        this.DisplayName = String.Empty;
        this.IsFullAddress = address.IndexOf('@') >= 0;
    }

    public CustomMailAddress(MailAddress address)
    {
        this.Address = address.Address;
        this.DisplayName = address.DisplayName;
        this.IsFullAddress = true;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if ((obj is CustomMailAddress y))
        {
            return this.IsFullAddress ? this.Address.EndsWith(y.Address) : y.Address.EndsWith(this.Address);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Address.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```