# Subquery with joins in LINQ

Tags: linq

I am new to LINQ. I am confusing to query it. Please any one tell me how to convert the below query in LINQ

```
select * from tbldev 
where iddevice not in(select a.iddevice from 
tblUDMap a join tbldev d 
on a.iddevice=d.iddevice )
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183791/how-would-you-do-a-not-in-query-with-linq

Answer (score 2):

A literal and naive word to word translation would be something like this:

```
    var result = from dev in context.tbldev
                 where (from udmap in context.tblUDMap join dev2 in context.tbldev on udmap.iddevice equals dev2.iddevice select udmap.iddevice)
                       .Contains(dev.iddevice) == false
                 select dev.iddevice;
```

But your question is strange! You jon the two tables and then filterout those rows in `tbldev` that were successfully participated in join! It means you want those rows in `tbldev` which cannot be joint to tblUDMap. So it is more simple to write this:

```
var result = from dev in context.tbldev 
             where (from udmap in context.tblUDMap 
                    where udmap.iddevice == dev.iddevice
                    ).Count() == 0
             select dev.iddevice;
```

Comment: @Kalyan Sorry! Corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for nested queries here:

```
from x in tbldev
join y in tblUDMap
    on x.iddevice equals y.iddevice
    into grp
where !grp.Any()
select x
```

This will select all records from `tbldev` for which there are no corresponding records in `tblUDMap`.

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify your query to something like this

```
var query = tbldev.Where(e => !tblUDMap.Any(a => a.iddevice == e.iddevice))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
from res in tbldev
where !(from a in tblUDMap
        join b in tbldev on a.Iddevice equals b.iddvice
        into c
        select c)
select res
```

The important part is the negated `where`-clause. the join syntax in this might not be correct, from the top of my head.