# NOT IN Condition in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have a simple scenario.I want to list out all the employees except the logged in user.

Similar SQL Condition is

```
select * from employee where id not in(_loggedUserId)
```

How can I acheive the above using LINQ.I have tried the following query but not getting the desired list

```
int _loggedUserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["LoggedUserId"]);

List<int> _empIds = _cmn.GetEmployeeCenterWise(_loggedUserId)                              
                        .Select(e => e.Id)
                        .Except(_loggedUserId) 
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you do a "not in" query with LINQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183791/how-would-you-do-a-not-in-query-with-linq)

Comment: Your select could be select * from employee where id <> _loggedUserId and then you do not need the IN operator.

Comment: Try `.Where(e => e.Id != _loggedUserId)` instead of `Except`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Except` expects argument of type `IEnumerable<T>`, not `T`, so it should be something like

```
_empIds = _cmn.GetEmployeeCenterWise(_loggedUserId)                              
                           .Select(e => e.Id)
                           .Except(new[] {_loggedUserId}) 
                           .ToList();
```

Also note, this is really redundant in the case when exclusion list contains only one item and can be replaces with something like `.Where(x => x != _loggedUserId)`

Answer (score 3):

The title of your question is how to perform a *not in* query against a database using LINQ. However, as others have pointed out your specific problem is better solved by a using `users.Where(user => user.Id != loggedInUserId)`.

But there is still an answer on how to perform a query against a database using LINQ that results in `NOT IN` SQL being generated:

```
var userIdsToFilter = new[] { ... };
var filteredUsers = users.Where(user => !userIdsToFilter.Contains(user.Id));
```

That should generate the desired SQL using either Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL.

Entity Framework also allows you to use `Except` but then you will have to project the sequence to ID's before filtering them and if you need to original rows you need to fetch them again from the filtered sequence of ID's. So my advice is use `Where` with a `Contains` in the predicate.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a very simple `Where` condition?

```
_empIds = _cmn.GetEmployeeCenterWise(_loggedUserId).Where(e=>e.Id != _loggedUserId).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ without filtering. This will make your query execute much faster:

```
List<int> _empIds = _cmn.GetEmployeeCenterWise(_loggedUserId)                              
                    .Select(e => e.Id).ToList();
```

Now use `List.Remove()` to remove the logged-in user.

```
_empIds.Remove(_loggedUserId);
```