# Know what id is not present

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a SQL table :

```
Id  FirstName   LastName    DateTime
1   John        Doe         2016-09-27 20:45:52.293
2   John        Doe         2016-09-27 20:45:53.620
3   John        Doe         2016-09-27 20:46:02.370
4   John        Doe         2016-09-27 20:46:02.533
5   John        Doe         2016-09-27 20:46:02.680
6   John        Doe         2016-09-27 20:46:02.820
```

And one `List<Int>` :

```
List<int> ids = new List<int>(){ 2, 3, 5 }
```

I use Linq To Sql class for get all record in my sql table. I do :

```
using(DataClassesDataContext Context = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
    var Customers = Context.Customers;
}
```

I want to know if all the ids on the list are present in the table and if not, find out what line is not present

What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you do a "not in" query with LINQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183791/how-would-you-do-a-not-in-query-with-linq)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in `LINQ` to find all missing customer details

```
var missingCustomers = Customers.Where(c => !ids.Any(i => i == c.Id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

"I want to know if all the ids on the list are present in the table and if not, find out what line is not present"

To find out if **all** the ids on the list are present in the table:

```
bool check = ids.All(i => Customers.Select(s => s.Id).Contains(i));
```

To find out what customers are **not** present (similar to some other answers here):

```
var missingCustomers = Customers.Where(c => !ids.Contains(c.Id)).ToList();
```

**Edit**

For the reverse (find missing Ids in table):

```
var allTableIds = Customers.Select(s => s.Id).ToList();
var missingCustomersIDs = ids.Where(c => !allTableIds.Contains(c)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to know what ids are not present in table (missings Ids in table)

Comment: Try the edited part, its untested, so let me know if it works out.