# C# How to use "not in" in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Please show me how to use "not in" using LINQ

Given the SQL :

```
select count(*) from Customer
where (ID = @Id and substring(CustomerIndicator, 1, 1) 
not in(@custInd1, @custInd2, @custInd3))
```

My Attempt:

```
        var results = (from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                       where r.Field<string>("ID") == row["ID"].ToString()
                            && !(r.Field<string>("CustomerIndicator").Substring(1, 1) == "X" || "Y" || "Z")
                       select r).Count();
```

Comment: What type is `dt`?

Comment: dt is a DataTable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/183804/1006272 - is this what your're looking for?

Comment: I was writing a longer explanation, but it's closed now, so whatever here's a fiddle... https://dotnetfiddle.net/nb0hhf