# Subquery in using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I have two tables.

1) `Employee` which have `Id, Name, DeptId` columns.

2)  `Department` which have `Id and DeptName` columns.

I want to find all department which have no any employee using Linq to sql.

IN sql I use below query:

```
Select * from Department Where Id not in 
(Select DeptId from Employee where DeptId Is not Null )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `LINQ` *left join* like this:-

```
var result = from d in departments
             join e in employees
             on d.Id equals e.DeptId into es
             from x in es.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where x == null
             select new Department { Id = d.Id, Name = d.Name};
```

Check this [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tnRQFw) for example with some custom objects.

In `SQL` this is equivalent to:-

```
SELECT D.*
FROM Department D
LEFT JOIN Employee E
   ON D.Id = E.DeptId
WHERE E.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work for you.

```
var empWithDepartments = from emp in Employee where emp.DeptId != NULL select emp.DeptId;
var result = from dep in Department where !empWithDepartments.Contains(dep.Id) select dep;
```

Comment: your answer is correct but I want result in one linq. Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var query = from d in Departments
 where !(from e in Employees select e.FkDepartmentId).Contains(d.DepartmentId)
select d;
```

According to [this post](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183791/how-would-you-do-a-not-in-query-with-linq,) this would work with LINQ-TO-SQL but not with LINQ-TO-EF.