# Lambda where id does not exist in another list

Tags: c#, lambda

I have to exclude items whose ids exist in another list.

```
List<Int64> Listofid;
var filteredlist = curProjArea.Project.ForEach(x => {x.ProjectId = (where 
 project id does not exist in Listofid) });
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You could've searched SO before posting the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you do a "not in" query with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183791/how-would-you-do-a-not-in-query-with-linq)

Answer (score 2):

You can filter projects in Where clause:

```
List<Int64> Listofid;
var filteredlist = curProjArea.Project.Where(x => !Listofid.Contains(x.ProjectId));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Int64> Listofid;
var filteredlist = curProjArea.Project.Where(x =>  !Listofid.Contains(x.ProjectId)).ToList();
```

Try this out once

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] values1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

// Contains three values (1 and 2 also found in values1).
int[] values2 = { 1, 2, 5 };

// Remove all values2 from values1.
var result = values1.Except(values2);

// Show.
foreach (var element in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

From:
https://www.dotnetperls.com/except

Comment: `Except()` doesn't work because `Project` is a object

Answer (score 0):

I think , It's useful for you

```
List<Int64> Listofid = new List<Int64>() { 5, 3, 9, 7, 5, 9, 3, 7 };
List<Int64> filteredlist = new List<Int64>()  { 8, 3, 6, 4, 4, 9, 1, 0 };
List<Int64> Except = filteredlist.Except(Listofid).ToList();
Console.WriteLine("Except Result");
foreach (int num in Except)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ", num); //Result =  8,6,4,1,0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just negate the `.Contains` on the list for which you want to exclude it.

```
var filteredList = curProjArea.Project.Where(a => !Listofid.Contains(a.ProjectId));
```

[Demo in Dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RCeIJH)

Comment: ah... Missed it. Thank you @fubo