# How to pass a list of strings through webapi and get the results without those strings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

My code already gets the table without containing a string. How can I get a list without containing a list of strings? I want to get the result of `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column NOT IN ('x' ,'y');`

```
public IEnumerable<keyart1> Get(string keyword)
{
    List<keyart1> keylist;
    using (dbEntities5 entities = new dbEntities5())
    {

        keylist = entities.keyart1.Where(e => e.keyword != keyword).ToList();
        var result = keylist.Distinct(new ItemEqualityComparer());
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part do you need help with?  Do you want to know how to select from a list where the keyword is not in a list of items?

Comment: i want to select the whole table where the column keywords doesn't contain x,y,z.

Comment: See the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183791/how-would-you-do-a-not-in-query-with-linq

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the answer if anybody interested

```
public IEnumerable<keyart1> Get([FromUri] string[] keyword1)
{
    List<keyart1> keylist;
    List<IEnumerable<keyart1>> ll;
    using (dbEntities5 entities = new dbEntities5())

    {
        ll = new List<IEnumerable<keyart1>>();
        foreach (var item in keyword1)
        {
            keylist = entities.keyart1.Where(e => e.keyword != item).ToList();
            var result = keylist.Distinct(new ItemEqualityComparer());
            ll.Add(result);
        }
        var intersection = ll.Aggregate((p, n) => p.Intersect(n).ToList());
       return intersection; 
    }
}
```