# .NET 6 IntersectBy and ExceptBy examples

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-6.0

Could someone provide me a small example on how to Use the .NET 6 LINQ `IntersectBy` and `ExceptBy` methods? MSDN hasn't got any examples and the one I tried doesn't compile due to CS0411 error. The example I tried:

```cs
namespace Test
{
    internal struct Example
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{X}, {Y}";
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var elements = new List<Example>
            {
                new Example { X = 10, Y = 20 },
                new Example { X = 11, Y = 23 },
            };

            var elements2 = new List<Example>
            {
                new Example { X = 10, Y = 12 },
                new Example { X = 44, Y = 20 },
            };


            //ok
            var union = elements.UnionBy(elements2, x => x.X);
            
            //CS0411 - Why ?
            var intersect = elements.IntersectBy(elements2, x => x.X);

            //CS0411 - Why ?
            var except = elements.ExceptBy(elements2, x => x.X);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Granted the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersectby?view=net-6.0) doesn't have any examples, it states that the selector function should select `TKey` i.e. the type of the second collection. The following should work:

```
var intersect = elements.IntersectBy(elements2, x => x);
var except = elements.ExceptBy(elements2, x => x);
```

Although I think this may be closer to what you want:

```
var intersect = elements.IntersectBy(elements2.Select(e => e.X), x => x.X);
```

For more complex types, you may want to consider implementing an IEqualityComparer and using the overloads that take one as an argument.

Comment: I wonder why they choose to use a different pattern with `UnionBy` vs `IntersectBy` and `ExceptBy`.

Comment: Exactly, That got me confused as well.

Comment: The comments on the functions read the same, that the 2nd argument should be a "Key Selector", this almost seems like someone made a mistake somewhere in either the documentation or the framework code. The pattern in `UnionBy` seems to be what I would expect the others to look like as well.

Comment: The args in UnionBy are different though (IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,TKey>). Not saying it isn't confusing but I think the distinction is that Union requires items from both collections to produce the result while Intersect and Except only require items in the source collection and the comparison key.

Comment: @BradleyUffner The answer to that is IMO because `UnionBy` needs to return a single list of joined results, so they need to be the same type. Whereas `IntersectBy` and `ExceptBy` only return results from the source collection, so with these parameters you can use an `IEnumerable<TKey>`, and if you need to select from a different collection just use `Select` (which wouldn't really make sense for `UnionBy`)

Comment: At the bottom of the documentation you can find some [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/standard-query-operators/set-operations?branch=main#intersect-and-intersectby).

Answer (score 5):

I made my own `ExceptByProperty` method like this

Usage:

```
var new = items.ExceptByProperty(duplicateItems, x => x.Id).ToList();
```

Code:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptByProperty<TSource, TProperty>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, Func<TSource, TProperty> keySelector)
    {
        return first.ExceptBy(second, x => x, GenericComparer<TSource, TProperty>.Comparer(keySelector));
    }

}

public sealed class GenericComparer<T, TProperty> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    public static IEqualityComparer<T> Comparer(Func<T, TProperty> selector)
    {
        return new GenericComparer<T, TProperty>(selector);
    }

    private readonly Func<T, TProperty> selector;

    public GenericComparer(Func<T, TProperty> selector)
    {
        this.selector = selector;
    }

    public bool Equals(T? x, T? y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;

        return Equals(selector(x), selector(y));
    }

    public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] T obj)
    {
        object? value = selector(obj);

        if (value == null) return obj.GetHashCode();

        return value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of additional extension methods that more closely resemble the built-in version of `UnionBy`. Should make things a bit more consistent.

```
using System.Linq;

public static class MyExtensions 
{
    /// <inheritdoc cref="Enumerable.ExceptBy{TSource, TKey}(IEnumerable{TSource}, IEnumerable{TKey}, Func{TSource, TKey}, IEqualityComparer{TKey}?)"/>
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        return first.ExceptBy(second.Select(keySelector), keySelector);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc cref="Enumerable.IntersectBy{TSource, TKey}(IEnumerable{TSource}, IEnumerable{TKey}, Func{TSource, TKey}, IEqualityComparer{TKey}?)"/>
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> IntersectBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
         return first.IntersectBy(second.Select(keySelector), keySelector);
    }
}
```