# How to compare two lists and find out the position of the changed content

Tags: c#

```
public class Editor
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string BaseContent { get; set; }    
    public string LineNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I have below data in list

[image]

I have below data in another list

[image]

If you see above two list only in Line number 2 content has been changed.

Original content:

> Charterers hire the Vessel for the period together with any optional
> exten-

Changed Content

> This is new content Charterers this too hire the Vessel for the period
> together with any optional exten-

So I would like to frame a new list / get output something like below

[image]

So in output i would like to capture the changed content from original and character positions of these added texts. I am trying hard to find some logic  can someone help me to build this any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Don't know what version of dotnet you are using, but if you are using the 6 or above check the intersetby, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70135623/net-6-intersectby-and-exceptby-examples

Comment: Looks like edit distance / edit procedure (Levenstein algorithm): you want know how the original list is edited (inserted, updated or deleted). Original algorithm deals with characters in the string, in your case it will be items in the list

Comment: @DmitryBychenko do you have example?

Comment: @Niranjan: something like this - https://dotnetfiddle.net/kS6RJh - first I find changed (inserted, edited, deleted) items, then provide details on what exactly is edited. I've implemented a nuget package Literatu to operate with the strings (ToEdit is an extract from there) - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Literatu

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time and explaing this algortihm. I need some time to understand this i will go through it now..

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I have created fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/S9CqA7 here results looks confusing me, will it be possible to explain? Thanks

Comment: @Niranjan: First I compare items by both `BaseContent` (weight `1`) and then `LineNumber` (weight `0.5`). If item should be edited I show editing procedure. I've changed format slightly, https://dotnetfiddle.net/kS6RJh, may be it's more readable now.